# Building a universal swift framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, swift4.2

I'm building a hybrid framework with swift and objective-C. The framework was built with xcode and swift4.2. Now when I try to import it to xcode 9 I encounter an error "Module compiled with Swift 4.2 cannot be imported in Swift 4.1.2". Is there any way to over come this?

My director structure looks like this.

[image]

I'm planning to ship this pod via cocoapods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to over come this?

No. If you wanted to be able to use the framework in Xcode 9, you shouldn't have built it in Xcode 10.